# iOS NSDateformatter issue - dateFromString returning same (incorrect) time regardless of input string

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Not sure what I'm missing here. The following code returns a valid NSDate but with an incorrect time.

In fact it doesn't matter what the dateString's time returned is always incorrect so I don't think it is a timezone issue but a formatter issue.

```
NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+HH:mm"];
[inputFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];

NSString *dateString = @"2013-07-26T19:45:00+01:00";

NSDate *theDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

// returns an NSDate of 2013-07-26 01:00 BST or 2013-07-26 00:00 in NSLog
```

Anyone spot where I'm going wrong? Thanks, M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is a small mistake in your date formate, you are not handeling the date offset (timezone). `NSDateFormatter` will not pick the latest found time as the time not the timezone.

In your code `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+HH:mm` you are parsing the time twice, you should use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ`. the `ZZZZ`specifies the time zone.
Be aware that this code will only work on iOS6 and higher, if you need support for iOS 5 you should remove the `:` from the timezone.

Comment: Interesting about the the iOS version difference in the time zone... Do you happen to have a reference for that off-hand?

Comment: Thank you so much. I had tried with a Z ! I'd been starting at the locale markup guide for so long, I just couldn't see where I was going wrong. I really appreciate your response.

Comment: It's actually the `ZZZZZ` that is new to iOS 6, not `ZZZZ`.  However, NSDate seems to randomly just "get it" which confuses me a lot.  According to the reference page four-Z (`ZZZZ`) should be the same between iOS 5 and 6.  @CarlVeazey This is the page that lists parsing grammar vs ios version -> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html